# Feasibility of building a benchtop chip fab for prototyping

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors, chip-design

This is generally quite a vague question as I'm new to the space but I've been thinking a lot about prototyping in the IC/semiconductor space and have been wondering about the feasibility of developing a small scale/benchtop system that is capable of making cmos chip prototypes.

Can anyone who knows more about this fill in the gaps here and tell me where I'm likely wrong? Why or why not would a system like this work? How would one go about building something like this?

Comment: Have you ever seen how the actual ICs are manufactured? Clean rooms and millions worth equipment?

Comment: Other end of @EugeneSh. scale - garage lithography by Applied Science. Link: https://youtube.com/watch?v=YAPt_DcWAvw

Comment: @winny I'm too lazy to watch the whole video. What kind of ICs are they able to produce? Or they don't, just the masks?

Comment: @EugeneSh. There actually are desktop scale processing cells for prototype IC production. A whole setup needed to do basic cmos process costs maybe $1.5M and runs in normal office air. The cells are gas tight and the wafers are moved around in gas-tight cartridges. No clean room necessary. At this point, all this tech needs is volume to make it cheaper. The biggest cost long run will be process chemicals and their disposal. It’s surprisingly expensive.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well, I wonder if this is what the OP is asking about, or they are interested in some kind of hobby-scale product.

Comment: Ask around at local colleges.  Heck, my daughter took a Nanotechnology course at the community college and she made IC's using a contact (non-lithographic) technique.

Comment: If your intention is to make digital logic... just forget about it and use PAL or FPGAs instead.   Much easier!  (Google will explain what those are 4 u)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Would you be able to share more details around desktop scale processing cells? Any links?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just the lithography step. If your transistors are large enough, it’s doable in a garage with enough time and patience.

Comment: @sam There are lots of aspects to your question and I frankly don't know exactly what you care about. Sounds a little more like some kind of survey of the landscape is what you want to wander around and play inside of, to me. Can't do that for you. But I have been able to borrow a wire-bonder and get some training in using one for a project I had in mind. That's one part of your question. Another might be in FAB processing. I've built a small lamp-heated nickel plated water cooled quartz FAB chamber before. And you can control the ramp rates, as well. That's all doable. But...

Comment: @sam The gases (contrary to what Kuba mentioned) are also quite cheap ($50 two decades ago bought a bottle of Arsine from California.) But they are VERY dangerous and it is all the stuff you need to make the environment safe for their application, which will kill your budget. That, plus all the regs related to owning and using them. Silane, Arsine, Phosphine, etc., are EXTREMELY dangerous gases. Used to be the gases were not regulated across state boundaries. I think that's changed. You have lithography and all the processing between steps. In all, it's expensive to set up at home.

Comment: @sam However, there are initiatives that you can use: [this one](https://www.fossi-foundation.org/), for example. And if you have some cash to spend, the cost of working through brokers to gain access to FAB facilities to buy a processed wafer or even a partial of a processed wafer is also very much cheaper to consider than it once was. Anyone with a little cash and sufficient motivation can likely get something done. You may also need someone to pre-test, mark bad dies, and then cut your dice, someone to perform prepackage testing and packaging. But more affordable, today, than ever it was.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Please give us a link or more information about this desktop fab you mentioned. You didn't mention anything about how the lithography and gate oxide growth are accomplished, and I am particularly interested in those steps.

Comment: @jonk As far as I can tell, FOSSi is only intended to assist with standards and interchange for IP and not with actual fabrication of anything. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

Coincidentally, Sam, you want to learn from another Sam, [Sam Zeloof.](http://sam.zeloof.xyz/)

He's managed to produce one or two devices a year with a few thousand transistors. This is really impressive, but still not all that useful for non-toy purposes.

However, I don't think this is something that can be deskilled and productized like a 3D printer. The chemistry is pretty toxic as well.

Comment: "The chemistry is pretty toxic as well." I worked at a defense lab that had a group with their own small-scale fab lab. One guy worked over the weekent, and on Monday was found dead. He had apparently inhaled arsine or phosphine, both used as dopants.

Comment: Out of curiosity - can you elaborate on why deskilling this to something like a 3d printer is infeasible? What are the main constraints around doing something like that?

Comment: @sam The success of modern CMOS **relies completely** on the ability to grow (not **deposit**, not **print**) extremely thin and extremely high quality oxide layers. It is simply far beyond any 3D printing technology.